# How to handle an audio file uploaded using PhoneGap in a c# mvc.net application controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, cordova

I am using PhoneGap API to record audio files (.wav) from iOS devices. I want to upload the recorded audio file to the application server (an asp.net c# mvc application).

I'm using the 'upload' method provided by PhoneGap's FileTransfer object to upload the file to the server as shown in this [documentation page](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html).

Assuming that my controller will be something like http://myapp.com/Media/UploadAudio, I want to know how to handle the file upload in the server side controller (method code) so that I can save the file to the filesystem.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? what didn't work ? any error messages/exception ? please show some source code...

Answer (score 4):

I've handled it :)

Here is the code I used:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadAudio()
    {

        HttpFileCollectionBase Files = Request.Files;

        bool fileSaved = false;

       foreach (string h in Files.AllKeys)
       {
           if (Files[h].ContentLength > 0)
           {
               string fileName = Files[h].FileName; 
               int fileSize =Files[h].ContentLength;

               string serverPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("..\\Your\\Favorite\\Location\\"));

               if (!Directory.Exists(serverPath))
               {
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath);
               }

               try
               {
                    //Get & Save the File
                    Request.Files.Get(h).SaveAs(serverPath + fileName);
                    fileSaved = true;
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               { 

               }

           }
       }
        return Json(new {FileSaved = fileSaved});
    }
```