# Asp.net MVC Upload audio files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, audio

Ok so I have a web application that I am trying to set up to allow a user to upload an audio file via httpPost.  The problem I have is that the function I am using takes in the files as an HttpPostedFileBase.  When I debug I can see the file format as an audio format but I can't seem to convert it.  I did something similar with an image by using MemoryStream but I don't know if there is something similar for audio formats.  Here is what I have on the client side to upload the files.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value ="ok" />
}
```

On the server side I have this.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {            
            return View();
        }
```

Now what I am trying to accomplish is have that variable file converted into an mp3 format that I can use in a player of some sort.   I am purposely avoiding using a file system where I store this file, it will be stored via database as a whole so I can't use the paths.  I am trying to play the file directly.  The ideas that I have looked into are changing the input type on the cshtml from "file" to something else that might work or finding a way to convert the HttpPostedFileBase would work as well.  Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added?

under  
add

If still issue persist check this
http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2012/04/20/file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc3.aspx

[How to handle an audio file uploaded using PhoneGap in a c# mvc.net application controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486725/how-to-handle-an-audio-file-uploaded-using-phonegap-in-a-c-sharp-mvc-net-applica)

Comment: That shows you how to upload images which I can do its the Audio Files that are giving me a problem. With the image uploads there is a method to convert to an image format, I need the same for an audio format.